# Is there a single word meaning "very funny book"?

Tags: single-word-requests, books, humor

Sometimes you read a book that has you convulsing with laughter from the moment you pick it up.  For me, one of those books was *Catch-22* by Joseph Heller.  What do you call this?

Perhaps there isn't a single word or standard phrase for it but I'm convinced there is and I just can't remember it.  It would be much like *potboiler* means a poor quality book, the kind of pulp rubbish people buy in airports.

Comment: "You have to read Catch-22. It's a riot!"

Comment: @mkennedy - Add usage example or a citation, and you have a decent answer.  It's only a single word request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term doesn't really solely apply to books, but I would say that the book is a [sidesplitter](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sidesplitter):

> a joke that seems extremely funny

Similar words to this (to describe things that are very funny, though maybe not necessarily a book) are:

- riot (or "laugh riot")
- scream
- knee-slapper
- thigh-slapper

Comment: I thought of side-splitter myself but it didn't feel right for a whole book.  Riot is my favourite one!

Comment: ... and rib-tickler too.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with "very funny" for a very funny book? Other alternatives could be, hilarious, and uproarious. As mentioned above, riot, and side-splitter also qualify.